# XPath to match @class value and contains numbers?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I would like to locate only this element,

`795229118062` from that `<div class="spec_info"> '795229118062</div>`

using XPath which says select div elements whose class attribute equals "spec_info" and whose content contains a numbers. Need to add something to this `//*[contains(@class,'spec_info')]`

```
<div class="details_specification">
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <div class="spec_title">
                                    Category
                                </div>
                                <div class="spec_info">
                                    
                                        <a href="/category.jhtm?cid=112">Housewares</a>
                                    
                                        , <a href="/category.jhtm?cid=133">Food Containers</a>
                                    
                                        , <a href="/category.jhtm?cid=111">Baskets</a>
                                    
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <div class="spec_title">
                                    Casepack Dimension
                                </div>
                                <div class="spec_info">
                                    17,90L x 12,80W x 8,50H
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="clearfix">
                                <div class="spec_title">
                                    UPS Number
                                </div>
                                <div class="spec_info">
                                    '795229636986
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                                <div class="clearfix">
                                    <div class="spec_title">
                                        Product Color
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="spec_info">
                                        GRAY
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Your XML sample doesn't have **795229118062** value anywhere. Please fix the sample.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath

```
//div/div[3]/div[2]/text()
```